# How do I infer that vectors equation from this subspaces "equation"?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have 3 subspaces: $U,V,W$.

My source tells me that if $u \in (U \cap V+U \cap W)$,
then $u=v+w$, where $v \in U \cap V$ and $w \in U \cap W$.

Now I wonder why that's true because how do I know for sure that a random  vector from the subspace area of $U \cap V+U \cap W$, is equal to a sum of two random vectors from $v \in U \cap V$ and $w \in U \cap W$. I mean I know it belongs to the same group as them because of the subspaces law, but how do I know it is actually equal to their sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's by definition. What does $A + B$ mean? It means the set of ALL possible vectors $a + b$, where $a$ is a vector in $A$ and $b$ is a vector in $B$.

So in this case, we have that $u \in (U \cap V) + (U \cap W)$. What does that mean? It means that there are vectors $v$ and $w$ such that $v \in U \cap V$, $w \in U \cap W$, and $u = v + w$.

Comment: I just don't quite understand the transition between **u belongs to** and **u equal to**.if **(U∩V)+(U∩W)** is the combination of all **v + w** and **u** belongs to it how do I infer every **u** is equal to a combination of some **v+w** ? I can't quite connect between the **∈** and **=** worlds.

Comment: @user3575645 the definition of "$A + B$" where $A$ and $B$ are vector subspaces is this: you belong to $A + B$ exactly when you are equal to the sum of a vector in $A$ and a vector in $B$. So *belongs to* in this case is by definition. And that's why you know that it is equal to the sum of some $v + w$.